# What is the .Z for acceleration on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, core-motion

I am using Core Motion on my app. I know that the .X is moving the iPhone along the long axis and the .Y is moving the iPhone across the short axis. But I do not know what the .Z is reading, so if anyone could explain that to me it would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does the iPhone accelerometer measure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293850/what-exactly-does-the-iphone-accelerometer-measure)

Comment: I am looking for what the .Z does in the accelerometer not the accelerometer in general.

Comment: Read the answerrs there.

Comment: You know that these kind of things are **very** easily googleable or even testable.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm sure there are a zillion duplicates but that isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z axis is what you'd be using if you smashed the screen of the iPhone into your forehead.

By the way, this statement is not quite right: "I know that the .X is moving the iPhone along the long axis". Core Motion cannot detect *moving* (despite the name). It detects *acceleration*, which is not quite the same thing. You can move without accelerating (also known as constant velocity), and you can accelerate without moving (also known as gravity).

Comment: So its moving the iPhone up and down?

Comment: No, the screen can be facing any direction. Hold it out in front of you and smash it horizontally into your forehead - it's still the Z axis. Imagine a line shooting orthogonally out of the front of the screen. We're talking about acceleration in that direction.